# What is the maven repository for jconn4.jar?

Tags: java, maven, sybase, jconnect

jConn3 is the only one I can find.

'com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc:jconn3:6.05'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My research tells me that jconn3.jar and jconn4.jar are part of Sybase jConnect.  In order to download (at least) the latest version of jConnect, you need to "register" an account ... and maybe do other stuff like a click-through license.  (I'm not giving them my email address just to find out.)

Based on that, *I suspect* that the copy of jconn3.jar you can see in Maven Central is unauthorized, and should not be there.

My advice would be to:

1. Register for an account on the Sybase site.
2. Download the JAR.
3. Add a copy of the JAR with a minimal POM file to either your local repo, or your private institutional repo.
4. Don't export it without reading the jConnect license carefully first to check that it is permitted.

If you are providing your software to 3rd parties, then check what the jConnect license says about this first.

If you intend to make your software available in a public Maven repo, you may need provide instructions on how downstream projects should deal with the jconn.jar problem.

---

The other approach might be to ask Sybase / SAP for permission to upload the JAR to Maven Central.

(I don't rate your chances though.  The fact that they have put the downloads behind a "signup" wall suggests that they want to track who is using jConnect for "business reasons".  Convincing them to change their strategy could be difficult.)

---

**UPDATE** - According to @Hlex's 2015 research (see below), the software is available for free from the SAP Store.  However, you still need to sign up for an account.

Comment: Having the audacity to require developers to register for the privilege of downloading your drivers is so 90s. That Sybase was caught in this time warp is one of the reasons it died the death it so desperately deserved and was begging for.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus as a developer trying to build an app for Sybase, I find this comment extremely accurate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jTDS drivers in central maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds) which is free to use and supports the latest Sybase ASE (16.0 SP4 as of now).

Comment: jtds (at least version 1.3.1) is JDBC 3.0 compliant, and not JDBC 4.0. This means it works fine for most basic query stuff, but advanced new features (like the getDatabaseSchema method used by Spring Batch) and other features are missing.

Answer (score 1):

This page provide how you download jconn4.jar.
http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/questions/23450/jconnect-software-developer-kit-download

You need to install to your local repo yourself.

Comment: This link is expired / points to a shady URL

Comment: Sorry, This comment is 8 years old :)

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't mean to blame you and only now noticed the abrasive tone, the comment was just meant to inform others that the link is not useful anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 11:

`pom.xml`:

```
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        </dependency>
...
```

And use:

- Driver class name: `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver`
- JDBC Url: `jdbc:jtds:sybase://SERVER:PORT/DATABASE`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work for you but I had one of my network admins sign into the server that had the Sybase installation and he looked under C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere {version_number}\Java and found the jar file.