# Cannot find the latest jconnect jar file for sybase drivers

Tags: java, jar, driver, sybase, jconnect

I was trying to get the latest jconn4.jar for the sybase drivers in my java project, but I cannot find the latest version of it.

Here are the links where I did find it but they are older versions:

> https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_id2d/downloads/jdbc%20drivers/jconn4.jar/
> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jdbc.sybase/jconnect

Also, the official link from older threads and articles that suggests this link which doesn't work because now its redirected to SAP portal

> http://www.sybase.com/products/allproductsa-z/softwaredeveloperkit/jconnect

From some of the discussions from threads, it says that now its a part of SAP ASE SDKs which I also downloaded from here:

> https://developers.sap.com/trials-downloads.html?search=jdbc

it has a jconnect folder but I couldn't find jconn4.jar file inside of it.
(a
Some of the links that I found useful are:

> [https://answers.sap.com/questions/676043/is-jconn4jar-still-available.html\](https://answers.sap.com/questions/676043/is-jconn4jar-still-available.html%5C)
> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349911/what-is-the-maven-repository-for-jconn4-jar\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349911/what-is-the-maven-repository-for-jconn4-jar%5C)
> https://answers.sap.com/questions/11348967/where-can-i-download-the-jconn4jar-for-sqla-16.html

Comment: fwiw, the last few releases of the `ASE SDK` can be found [here](https://developers.sap.com/trials-downloads.html) (search for `Adaptive` and download the link for your OS/hardware)

Comment: @markp-fuso thanks, I already did that, but it didn't contain jconn4.jar file... or am I missing something?

Comment: @markp-fuso found it thanks

Comment: I don't know if it's the right version but I found `jConnect-16_0/classes/jconn4.jar` when I downloaded/installed `SDK 16.0 SP03 PL07` (I just picked one of the linux installs)

Answer (score 0):

It is available was available here only, https://developers.sap.com/trials-downloads.html?search=jdbc.

the path for it is
jconnect.iam.zip$IA_MERGE_RESOURCES$\SAP jConnect_1625213170063\6070b025c74123f28e08328c3af4d70e\jdbc.manifest_za_ia_sf.jar\classes you will find jconn4.jar